# Grails: not finding plugin classes

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use STS for Grails development. When I install a plugin the IDE does not find some core classes of the plugin.

Example:

`import grails.plugins.nimble.core.AdminsService`

gives "Unable to resolve class import grails.plugins.nimble.core.AdminsService" .

The project runs OK.

Also, I can't find that classes myself in the project dir nor in Grails SDK dir. Where are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails uses the ivy dependency manager.  You'll find the plugin classes under `.ivy2/cache/org.grails.plugins/` in your home directory.

[This post](http://andrewclement.blogspot.com/2010/05/springsource-tool-suite-and-grails-13.html) might help you with your STS issue.